# Adding new app in appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

3 days ago I started using google appengine to see how it works.

I have set the basic app that prints "hello". Nothing complicated. I updated the simple app thet prints "hello" app and it worked perfectly.

Then I wanted to experiment a little more:

First I did is that I uploaded new program (i didint change app.yaml, just main.py)
Then i got a empty screen.

Then I uploaded a new version of app (changed version in app.yaml, and main.py), I have changed a versions in admin in backend. I still had a empty screen.

Thanks.

This is my code:
main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print 'Hello, World!'
```

app.yaml:

```
application: searchbarrel
version: 2
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

The app works good on localhost

Comment: you need to post your code. its pretty hard to guess whats wrong without any info. does your app work on the local SDK? what do you mean with `print`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can't work. its not enough to write a file that has a `print hello` inside. you need to create a WSGI app and make a RequestHandler that processes your request and writes the `hello world` out.

main.py

```
import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('Hello, World')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)])

def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([("/", MainPage)], debug=True)
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

you should read the getting started guide first.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/

Answer (score 2):

Your CGI script needs to print at least one blank line before outputting text, since the browser will take the first line to be an HTTP header:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print '\nHello, World!'
```

will work fine.

Ideally, you should print actual valid HTTP headers before your blank line.

dev_appserver acts a bit differently than the production servers, which is why you're seeing output running locally.

(It is a good idea to use a WSGI framework, however.)

Comment: are you sure about what you are saying? i don't think this will do anything without a WSGI app and a request handler... you cant print, where do you think will this print appear? its not a log message so not in the console and its not in a request handler so not in the broweser.

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely sure. Tested it myself. But thanks for the downvote.

Comment: Scripts in 2.5 (and 2.7 without threadsafe, if you designate a script instead of a WSGI application in app.yaml) are executed as CGI. Of course you can print; how do you think webapp sends output to the server?